# Images from amazon disappear after phonegap build

Tags: android, phonegap

In my app i get some images from amazon cloud.
Everything works in web and when it connected throw phonegap app.
But after build apk by phonegap service, my amazon images disappear in app.
What could be wrong, or how i can investigate reason of this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add access origin="*" to your config.xml
Or, of course, indicate the necessary sources.
And in my case, I need to add plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" to my config.xml as it says here http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/access-elements/